# How to fix "Error: bad operand types for binary operator" in generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, generic-collections

I am trying to print a specific range of contents in the array. And, I am required using the generic method, but I keep getting these errors, saying bad operand types for binary operator. I want to ask which part I did it wrong, and how can I fix the errors?

I am using drjava.

```
  Integer[ ] integerArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Double[ ] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5 };
  Character[ ] characterArray = { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };
  Pet[ ] petArray = { new Pet( "Bob", "Tortoise", "TSA", "19950315" ),
                      new Pet( "SweetPea", "Horse", "Genie", "20030214" ),
                      new Pet( "Little", "Chicken", "John", "20190123" ),
                      new Pet( "Dale", "Chipmunk", "Sam", "20090527" ),
                      new Pet( "Smokey", "Bear", "USPW", "19440413" )     };
  
  System.out.printf( "%nRange of integerArray contains:%n" );
  printRange( integerArray, 1, 3); 
  
  System.out.printf( "%nRange of doubleArray contains:%n" );
  printRange( doubleArray, 1, 3 ); 

  System.out.printf( "%nRange of characterArray contains:%n" );
  printRange( characterArray, 1, 3 ); 
  
  System.out.printf( "%nRange of petArray contains:%n" );
  printRange( petArray, 1, 3 );
 
} // end main
```

// This is the part I'm getting errors at

```
public static <T> void printRange( T[ ] inputArray, T start, T stop ){

 // display array elements 
 // Error:bad operand type T for unary operator '++' and Error: bad operand types for binar operator
 
    for( T element = start; element < stop; element++ )    
    {
        //Error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
        first type:  T
        second type: int
        // Error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='
        first type:  T
        second type: T
        //Error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
        first type:  T
        second type: T
        if( start < stop && start >= 0 && stop <= inputArray[inputArray.length-1] )
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s", element.toString( ) );
        }
   
    } // end enhanced for loop

    System.out.println( );
 
} // end method printRange                                    
} // end class ArrayMethods
```

This is the expected output.
Range of integerArray contains:

> 2 3
>
> 2.2 3.3
>
> E L

Comment: the generic type `T` can compare with `int`

Comment: If there is no type constraint on `T`, it will not have any arithmetic operators defined, including `++`. In a way it's like using the `Object` type, but without actually upcasting to `Object`. I have a feeling you're intending to use an indexed `for` loop, in which case your index counter should always be `int`.

Comment: okay i changed my code, but still showing one tiny error on "System.out.printf( "%s", element.toString );". It said Error: int cannot be dereferenced.
       
     } // end enhanced for loop

Answer (score 0):

Operation like `++`, `>`.. is allowed only for numerical types. You should use `int` type for `start` and `stop` variables. And it's easier to copy specific range of the source array to print it:

```
public static <T> void printRange(T[] inputArray, int start, int stop) {
    T[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, start, stop);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy));
}
```

**Update**: using `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    if (i >= start && i < stop) {
        System.out.printf("%s ", inputArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to this in a standard for loop instead of using copyOfRanfe( )?